# Default Docker Argument to UUID

Tags: docker, dockerfile, uuid, docker-build

Is it possible to default an `ARG` to a new unique ID if one has not been provided as a Build Argument?

Failing that is it possible to fail on build if a build argument is not provided?

Answer (score 0):

> Failing that is it possible to fail on build if a build argument is
>   not provided?

Yes, but then you should set any default value to `ARGS` in Dockerfile, or if set default value then you can ignore the default value in condition.

```
FROM alpine
ARG NODE_ENV
RUN if [ -z ${NODE_ENV} ];then \
    echo "No value provided for build ARGS, please provide NODE_ENV, like --build-arg NODE_ENV=dev" \
    exit 1; \
    else \
    echo "NODE_ENV is passed, value is ${NODE_ENV}"; \
    fi
```

So if you tried like

```
docker build --build-arg NODE_ENV=test -t test_arg .
```

It will build the image, but if you tired like

```
docker build  -t test_arg .
```

In this, the build will fail and will print a message to pass NODE_ENV

[image]